# Web Content-Management System ... Typo3, Joomla, ... isn't there any better solution out there?

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I tried many Content-Management Systems ... still being frustrated. I guess this topic comes up every once in a while. Here is it again. Typo3 is too complex, Joomla is only based on articles and doesn't support complex templates, Openengine is not any longer supported, user interfaces are complex. None of them have good support for modern designs, ... Which system are you using, which would you recommend?

needs:

- Simple user interface
- Usable for authors without any knowledge.
- Inline Editing
- ContentTemplates for front pages that the author can fill them.
- LayoutTemplate, Professional look and feel
- Modern Design. Sliders,etc.
- Simple to learn and develop
- ajax support
- simple extensible modules
- extranet
- Asset pool

Comment: Try some out here: http://opensourcecms.com

Comment: Believe me, I tried many. Don't have time right now to look through them all once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Plone http://plone.org/

It seems to have most of the features you want.

Comment: I took a look at it a while ago. They are using it my university. At that time I didn't want to learn Python. I really should consider taking closer look at it. Thx for your hint.

Answer (score 3):

Questions like these are so ridiculous. You want an open source thing that fits you needs, that's created in such a way you can understand it, that it has feature X that you need.. Why don't you start working on your own then? Open source CMS solutions are made like a shoe that fits on every foot. If you want to customize your site, you **WILL** have to input some effort. Nothing is easy, and there's nothing that will let you press a few buttons in a wizard of some sort that creates the thing you want to see.

I suggest either hiring someone to do what you want or simply man up and start doing it yourself. On the other hand, Wordpress is extremely modular and easy to understand code-wise even by PHP beginners.

Comment: I agree with N.B. - Perhaps try using a web framework such as CodeIgniter / Rails to get you up and running fast?

Comment: I fully agree you N.B.. I also tried wordpress, but I wouldn't recommend it as a content-management system. It is a blog! But from my experiences, you at least need some kind of html/web knowledge to work with all those systems. I want to have very narrow templates which get filled to maintain a professional look and feel. I believe there must be a cms has a "basic" view for non-professionals and than an advanced few for the administrators. I thought a couple of times of really starting my own cms. But nowadays you are lost if you do a one man show ... far too expensive.

Comment: And believe me, I know that you have to put effort into a cms. But, from my experiences as web developer most cmas are far to complex for unexperienced users. And sometimes those users don't want/don't have the time learn html and gain a better understanding of web content management and just want to use a system.